# What business make profit (with or without upgrades) when I purchase the supplies instead of stealing them?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

Let's say that I have all of business that takes supplies purchased:

- Which ones make profit when I purchase a full bar of supplies? (GTA$75.000)
- What if I have the Equipment, Staff or both upgrade?

Please note that "making profit" means that the total price of the product generated is over the value of the supplies, giving a profit margin.

Comment: As a general note, I prefer to sell in a full lobby - you get an additional 1% for each person in the lobby, which can add up to a substantial amount.

Comment: That is a good bonus, I always sell on lobbies that have at least 16 players. But before selling, I check if there are griefers or KD Farmers to make sure that my product is safe.

Comment: I check for the opposite reason ;) I love a good battle.

Comment: Fighting against other players while moving cargo sounds like a terrible combination. *sees group of Oppressors on the map from the same MC getting near*

Comment: In that case, it usually works to go ghost (make sure you are a CEO before starting), or have good friends :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two type of basic sales local and remote (+50% cash) I will break it down first amount will be local sale and second will be remote, and there is no difference if you upgrade only staff or equipment so there are 3 different amount of money you get(0 upgrade, 1 upgrade, full upgrade) and security upgrade doesn't make any difference at all.

### Bunker

1. Without upgrade: 100.000$ / 150.000$
2. With Staff or Equipment upgrade: 120.000$ / 180.000$
3. Fully upgraded: 140.000$ / 210.000$

On biker businesses when I bought supplies the amount of product I got was different, so it looks like this:

### Cocaine

1. Without upgrade: 60.000 - 90.000$ / 90.000 - 120.000$
2. With Staff or Equipment upgrade: 72.000 - 96.000$ / 108.000 - 144.000$
3. Fully upgraded: 84.000 - 112.000$ / 126.000 - 168.000$

### Meth Lab

1. Without upgrade: 51.000 - 68.000$ / 76.500 - 102.000$
2. With Staff or Equipment upgrade: 61.200 - 81.600$ / 91.800 - 122.400$
3. Fully upgraded: 71.400 - 95.200$ / 107.100 - 142.800$

### Counterfeit Cash

1. Without upgrade: 42.000 - 56.000$ / 63.000 - 84.000$
2. With Staff or Equipment upgrade: 50.400 - 67.200$ / 75.600 - 100.800$
3. Fully upgraded: 58.800 - 78.400$ / 88.200 - 117.600$

### Weed farm

1. Without upgrade: 36.000 - 48.000$ / 54.000 - 72.000$
2. With Staff or Equipment upgrade: 43.200 - 57.600$ / 64.800 - 86.400$
3. Fully upgraded: 50.400 - 67.200$ / 75.600 - 100.800$

### Document forgery ##

1. Without upgrade: 18.000 - 24.000$ / 27.000 - 36.000$
2. With Staff or Equipment upgrade: 21.600 - 28.800$ / 32.400 - 43.200$
3. Fully upgraded: 25.200 - 33.600$ / 37.800 - 50.400$

So to sum it up Bunker is profitable anytime, cocaine is profitable on remote sales or with upgrades, meth lab only with remote sales and upgrades, counterfeit needs upgrades and remote sale as well, weed farm only fully upgraded and remote sale and lastly document forgery is never going to be profitable with supplies bought.